# Firebase creating extra user data upon account creation

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase with Angular 2 to create new users. I would like to extend this by adding additional data for each newly created user. In this example, I would like to have every newly created user start with an assigned property of `net worth = 5000`. So my schema would look something like:

```
email | ''
password | ''
net worth | '5000'
```

Having gone through the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account), I have found the [save data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#write_update_or_delete_data_at_a_reference) feature. However, I am unsure how to merge the `set` feature with my username and password authentication script.

Below is the basic signup script.

```
signup(){
     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('johncena@nosell.com', 'ucantcme')
     .catch(function(error){
     console.log(error);
});}
```

I would like to know how to implement the `set` feature with this signup so I can add default data for users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't save 'net_worth' in the auth area. For that you need a seperate table in the database . For example 'users'. Check the below code.

After user creation you get **UID**. Using that UID store the related data into the database.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('johncena@nosell.com', 'ucantcme')
   .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.uid); // Created user UID

      var updates = {};
      updates['/users/' + response.uid] = { net_worth : 5000 };
      firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
});
```

Here 'users' is a new table.

Comment: Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'void | UserCredential'.
  Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)