# Firebase Angular 2 retrieving data from user table

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Below I have a signup code. This comes from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716203/firebase-creating-extra-user-data-upon-account-creation/39716306#39716306) I had about adding data to a user's table upon account creation. The code is as follows:

```
signup(){
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(useremail, userpassword)
   .then(function(response) {
      var updates = {};
      updates['/users/' + response.uid] = { email: useremail, password: userpassword, net_worth : 5000, username : 'Roy' };
      firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
});
}
```

To be clear, my schema should look something like:

```
email|''
password|''
username|'Roy'
net_worth|'5000'
```

Now I would like to retrieve this information and place it in my profile component, this time retrieving that data. At the moment what I have is the following:

**Profile Component**

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
private usermail: string;
private net_worth: string;
constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.usermail = '';
  this.net_worth = '';
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user != null) {this.usermail = user.email;}
}    
}
```

This code works for giving me the user's email from authentication, but it won't work in returning the other information in my schema, like `net_worth` and `username`. I imagine because it is stored in the database table, not the authentication function.

How would I call the user-generated ID to get the details of the specified user? Specifically, their `username` and `net_worth`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database structure is like this

```
Users
    user-Id1
        email
        net_worth
        username
```

After successful login, you can query your db based on the response returned from firebase. `uid`, just like you can access `email`, there is also `displayName` which can take the place of `username` for you. For more info on managing users [read here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

To query your db, for other info.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
    var getUserInfo = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
    getUserInfo.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val()); //returns net_worth, etc
    });
}
```